# Sahi scripting wait or time delay

Tags: sahi

I was wondering if someone could help me. I want to introduce a 10 minute wait or time delay within my sahi script.

Can someone confirm the correct command to use?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at the docs, the command you are looking for is _wait

https://sahipro.com/docs/sahi-apis/action-apis.html#Waits

Comment: _wait doesn't work i've tried it and after further investigation I discovered (maybe wrongly?) that all _wait does is wait the specified time OR until the page as loaded. As the page loads in seconds it ignores my _wait command...

Comment: Tell a lie. _wait does seem to work now. God knows what i did wrong the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Write _wait(parameter); where parameter is your the time in milli-seconds you want to introduce the delay for.

In your case try _wait(600000);

You can also use the setSpeed(parameter); API , in this case Sahi will wait for the time specified in milli-seconds as a parameter , after each task in the script. But I guess waiting 10 mins after each task is not your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

_wait($timeout, [$condition])

here $timeout is the duration you want to wait for. And $Condition is something that you can customize based on what condition you want to wait for. 
Or you can just use the overloaded method _wait($timeout) if you want to wait for a specific duration.

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply a conditional wait:

```
_wait(timeOut, _isVisible($element));
```

This will either wait till "timeOut" milliseconds, or till $element is visible. (whichever condition is satisfied earlier)